# Как проверить "облако"?

Tags: безударные-гласные

Как-то услышала, что безударную "а" в слове "облако" надо проверять словом "заволакивать"? 
Это однокоренные слова?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово ОБЛАКО заимствовано из ст.-сл. яз., в котором *облакъ* было сущ. м.р. Впоследствии в 
др.-рус. яз. оно преобразовалось в сущ. ср.р. Ст.-сл. *облакъ* развилось из ***обвлакъ**— тожд. в результате упрощения **бв > б**. Утрач. **обвлакъ** восходит к праслав. *ob-volkb «то, что обволакивает». В нем -ol- дало ст.-сл. -**ла**-. Ср. с полногласием -**оло**- рус. диал. **оболок, оболока** «туман, пары в высоте», оболоко «облако», собств. «то, что обволакивает».

Итак, этимология дает объяснение правописания гласной А в слове облако. Но! Этимология - это диахрония, т.е. исторический срез языка. В современном языке слова **облако** и **обволакивать** не являются однокоренными! Следовательно проверять первое вторым нельзя. Можно просто дать объяснение этимологии слова для запоминания.

Comment: Именно так. Даёт объяснение, но не проврочное слово. Ине нравится эта формклировка.

Comment: не хочется сводить всю проверку к подбору "однокоренного".
Этимология тоже может быть проверкой (хотя и более сложной). "Облако" служит примером.