# Как проверить "облако"?

Tags: проверочные-слова

В школе меня просто-таки изумляло, когда учительница приводила как проверочное "обволакивать". Но авторитет педагога давил, и я молчал.
Почему это меня изумляло, скажу после.
Дело в том, что с годами я для себя ответ получил, а заодно "открыл" одну интересную закономерность языка. Я охотно поделюсь и этой закономерностью, и другими соображениями, но сначала хочется услышать ответ на исходный, школьный вопрос.

Comment: Проще  было  бы  использовать  как  проверочное  слово - оболочка.  Чередование  оло - ла  в  этом  случае  отчетливей.

Comment: Облокачиваться никак не может быть проверкой к облаку и облатке, потому что слово облокачиваться это глагол от слова локоть. Облокотиться значит опереться на локоть.

Comment: @bernard - а зачем сюда еще какое-то чередование лепить? В *облако - обволакивать* нет никакого чередования.

Answer (score 2):

Обсуждали [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE)

Comment: спасибо за ссылку.
Мне кажется, что правильнее говорить, что слово было не "заимствовано", а унаследовано. Ведь мы же прямые потомки (по языку)старославянского, древнеболгарского и т.д.

Comment: Древнерусский  не  потомок  старославянского( древнеболгарского ),  а  близкий  родственник.  А  современный  русский  язык - потомок  древнерусского.

Answer (score 1):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

Заволочь (заволакивать, обволочь (обволакивать) - закрыть, подёрнуть, застлать; окружая собой со всех сторон, покрыть, укрыть что-л., окутать (о тучах, тумане, паре и т.п.).

ПРИМЕРЫ

Не было ни луны, ни звезд, ― должно быть, небо заволокло облаками. Дымом обволокло весь грузовик.Сумерки обволокли сад.

ОБЛАКО - это то, что ОБВОЛАКИВАЕТ небо, ЗАКРЫВАЕТ его (чередование бв/б). В древнерусском языке с 11 века в формах "облакъ и оболокъ". Существует диалектный русский вариант  - "оболоко". В словарях с 1731 года - "облак, облако" (возможно, ср.род появился только в 18 веке).

К ВОПРОСУ О ПРОВЕРКЕ

В этом случае отмечается типичное чередование древнерусского  ОЛО и старославянского ЛА: облако - оболочка, волочить - влачить, также: наволочка, которое можно и нужно использовать для проверки таких слов.

Comment: Всё правильно, остаётся заметить, что "обволакивать" не является проверкой (так же, как "откалывать" не является проверкой для "колоть"). Вот это меня и изумляло: учитель был неправ!

Comment: А "закономерность", о которой я сказал ранее, относится как раз к чередованию "бв-б".
Обнаружилось довольно много примеров этого чередования, не все очевидны. 
Кто-то может привести хотя бы некоторые?

Answer (score 0):

есть такое слово "облатка";в дном из своих значений - в аптечном,оно подошло бы,(как проверочное для слова "облако") и по смыслу и по звучанию.

Comment: чтобы использовать "облатка", нужно провести довольно большой этимологический экскурс.

И не уверен, что родство слов (облако - облатка) будет в результате бесспорно доказанным. 
Т.е. для практических целей не годится, по-моему

Comment: если "обволакивать" не является проверкой,то "облатка" не годится.Да и вообще:- кто же проверяет всем известные слова,словами редко употребляемыми...скорее наоборот.
А вот может быть глагол "облокачиваться" подойдёт?

Comment: Думаю, что само понятие проверки в данном случае имеет особый смысл. Это не приведение к сильной (ударной) позиции, а просто установление  факта чередования ОЛО/ЛА для данного корня, поэтому: ворота - вратарь, голова - глава.

Comment: ещё не рассмотрели "Чу́дище о́бло, озо́рно, огро́мно, стозе́вно и ла́яй"
  где "обло" приблизительно "тучный".В смысле "облакообразный"?
   Обло=туча=облако?  Болл - мяч.(круглое) Яблоко.(тоже круглое)

Comment: Мяч как шар и яблоко (почти шар) не круглые. Тень у них может быть кругом, срез.