# Каковы примеры чередования бв-б ?

Tags: этимология, чередования, историческая-грамматика

Мудрая София при обсуждении проверочных слов для "облако" совершенно справедливо указала на наличие в русском чередования 'бв-б' (см [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34043/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=34067#34067)). Пример: "о**бв**олакивать -- о**б**олочка -- о**б**лако". (чередование оло-ла, нас здесь уже не интересует).

А какие ещё примеры чередования 'бв-б' нам известны?

Answer (score 2):

Обод - обвод. 
Плюс производные.

Answer (score 1):

Забыть - забвение.

Comment: вот это да! никогда бы не подумал.
что-то мешает согласиться.  

"Забвение" от "забывать". Если 'в' выпало, то из "забывать" всё-таки. И дальше "бывать" -> "быть", т.е. скорее тут не чередование бв-б, а выпадение суффикса "ва". Нет?

Comment: А вот еще интересное чередование : вместо *я забыл про это* говорят *я забил на это*)

Answer (score 1):

Чередование бв/б: обладать - владеть, обычай (от обвычай), обет (от  обвет)

Comment: А  может  здесь  не  чередование,  а  выпадение  звука ?

Comment: Чередования разные бывают. Есть чередования звука с нулем, такое чередование можно назвать выпадением звука.